# why can't javascript find an element with a particular ID even if it is in the HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML DIV with an ID="0-0". I have javascript that is trying to call that ID. But it is giving an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. I'm not sure how to debug this, because Javascript is basically not acting the way that I would expect.

```
function getSurroundingIDs(id){
         var onesPlace = parseInt(id.split("-", 2)[0]);
         var tensPlace = parseInt(id.split("-", 2)[1]);  //split on -, return 2 tokens
         var IDs = new Array();
         for (var row=onesPlace-1;row<=onesPlace+1;row++){
             for (var col=tensPlace-1;col<=tensPlace+1;col++){
                 if(document.getElementById(row + "-" + col)){IDs[IDs.length]=row+"-"+col;}
            }
         }
     return IDs;
}
```

So why is `getElementByID(id)` returning null?

Comment: what's the role of the semi-colons in the html?

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of invalid text in your `<div>` tag?

Comment: Can't you just give a full code example that reproduces the issue instead of these partial code fragments and screenshots?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I removed the semi colons from the HTML and changed the IDs to start with a letter but I am still having the problem. I have posted the complete code now.

Comment: `document.getElementById(i+"-"+j)` should be `document.getElementById("c"+i+"-"+j)` in two spots in the `setNumbers()` function. Or use your `id` variable. `var id = "c" + i+"-"+j ;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. If you're not using HTML5 your ID is invalid. It must start with an English letter. Which might cause `getElementByID()` to not work properly..
2. What are these semicolons and javascript code before the div's
   attributes? You might have some other javascript that messes up your
   HTML code..

From the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You can use for example `id="div-0-0"`.

Note that (as @CrazyTrain stated in the comments) this restriction doesn't exist for HTML5, and most browsers fetch numeric IDs either way.

Comment: That restriction doesn't exist for HTML5, and I think browsers typically fetch numeric IDs either way.

Comment: @CrazyTrain You are right however OP didn't say which HTML version and which browser is he using, and the code seems relatively fine so I think this is the problem.

Comment: Will work in Chrome either way. Here's a demo using XHTML strict doctype http://jsbin.com/AWoM/1

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me are the semicolons in the tag and the 'return false'. If possible I'd clean the html a little.